# How do you add 2 specific people to a specific chat and then redirect them to another page in chat in django channels

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-channels, channel

I want to take anyone who connects to our server and immediately connect them with someone from our team and redirect both of them to a unique chat page. I don't know how to connect them with someone from our team and redirect both of them. I am stuck on that part.
I really appreciate the help.

I tried redirecting from the consumer page, but that did not seem to work whatever I did. It would get to the redirect and then do nothing. I then tried closing the socket connection and then redirecting them and that did not work either.
I am stuck on how to group them and redirect both of them.

**consumers.py**

```
class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

        # mine!

        # finds which user just connected to the websocket
        user = self.scope['user']
        print(user)
        ready.append(user)



    # trying to group person online and from our team
        # async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
        #     self.room_group_name,
        #     self.channel_name,
        #     ready[0],
        #     team[0],
        # )


        # trying different ways to redirect, none worked

        # self.disconnect(close_code=redirect('https://www.yahoo.com/'))
        # self.close()
        # redirecting()
        # ready.append(user)

        # print(ready[0])

        # self.disconnect(self.redirectIT('home'))
        #
        # raise channels.exceptions.StopConsumer
        # redirect('room', 'hi')
        # return redirecting()

        # self.close()
        # self.close()
```

I expected it to group the user and someone from our team but that didn't happen and instead gave me errors that it got more than needed arguments. The redirect did not throw out any errors but it did not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should do that all that in normal django views. The user sends a request and you create a chat and add a team member to it along with the user. Then the user is redirected to the page of the chat directly from the django view that handled the request. It is when he gets to the page that channels should now be used to send the chat messages through websocket. Everything before that should be done in a django view

Comment: i dont know who is on the website from either side and im using the web sockets to know who is on the channel in real time and then put them together in a room

Comment: @AugustusCaesar doesn't make any difference. Even with websocket you won't be aware of a new user until he tries to connect just as HTTP. You can redirect the user to the chat and then send a websocket message to the team member (whom you should already be aware of, else how would you contact him?). AFAIK there's no such thing as redirecting in websockets after the initial handshake as it is purely a HTTP concept.